# WebStorm jQuery auto complete not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ide, webstorm

After I installed WebStorm after formatting my computer the other day, jQuery auto-completion and code suggestion are not working.  This software worked perfectly before, but now jQuery is not working.  I tried reinstalling several times, but to no avail. This is the mouse-over notice for jQuery terms.

> Unresolved function or method
>   fadeOut()

Comment: Did you pay for it? You should be able to ask the JetBrains support for help. http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/WI Or the community forum. http://devnet.jetbrains.net/community/wi

Comment: @ Jared Farrish Yes,I wrote them also I submitted a message but no reply.This is the post link.

http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5308091#5308091

Thanx

Comment: If you're a paying customer, you should be able to raise an issue in their issue tracker.

Comment: yes I solved with their help.

Comment: If you provide a description in an answer for this question of what you did that worked, I'm sure fellow travelers would appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 11):

> For code completion to work you need jQuery to be either under your
>   project root or defined as global library (see Settings|JavaScript
>   Libraries).

from someone who has recently come from eclipse, that is like a cup of water in a desert.

Answer (score 9):

You can enable jQuery code completion by adding it as a global library in Webstorm and phpStorm.

- Go to   **Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Javascript** and click on **Libraries**.
- Click **Download** on the right side of the window.
- Select **Official libraries**, select `jQuery` in the list and click download
- jQuery would be enabled as a global library(shown below). Click Apply and ok.

[image]

Comment: In the 2022 version, it suggests to download the CDN link, setting it to global.